# эмуляция запроса axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Можно ли с axios проделать такую штуку:
при попытке сделать запрос axios фактически ничего не делает, а возвращает подставленные данные.
Необходимо для генерации моковых данных, т.е. при попытке обращения к api сервера axios не совершает никаких запросов, а в ответе лишь возвращает сгенерированный мок.

Comment: Да, такое можно сделать, воспользуйтесь [axios interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737078/how-can-you-use-axios-interceptors)

Comment: @MoloF да я именно в эту строну и смотрел... Но не понимаю как можно такое провернуть в interceptors.request, что-бы физический запрос к серверу не совершался вообще...

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего написать асинхронную функцию которая будет возвращать Promise с данными.

```
const getDataFromServer = async () => {
  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(yourDataHere), 1000);
  });
};
```

И вызывать её вместо axios. Пока данные "грузятся" можно отобразить спиннер. Так же можно в эту функцию добавить выдачу ошибки в определённый момент для тестирования. Например так:

```
const getDataFromServer = async () => {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(
      () => (Math.random() > 0.5 ? resolve(yourDataHere) : reject("Error msg")),
      1000
    );
  });
};
```